# ERROR while trying to install rpy2 using pip

Tags: python, rpy2

I'm trying to install `rpy2` using `pip install rpy2` on the command shell, but I get the following ERROR:

> Collecting rpy2   Using cached
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c7/43/401afad8556bf92b08bd7d422cacac614b0e8dd2bce31848318bbcb18f48/rpy2-3.0.5.tar.gz
>       ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>       ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "c:\users\pablo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py",
>   line 477, in **init**
>           self.vc_ver = self.find_available_vc_vers()[-1]
>       IndexError: list index out of range
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "c:\users\pablo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py",
>   line 157, in save_modules
>           yield saved
>         File "c:\users\pablo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py",
>   line 198, in setup_context
>           yield
>         File "c:\users\pablo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py",
>   line 248, in run_setup
>           DirectorySandbox(setup_dir).run(runner)
>         File "c:\users\pablo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py",
>   line 278, in run
>           return func()
>         File "c:\users\pablo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py",
>   line 246, in runner
>           _execfile(setup_script, ns)
>         File "c:\users\pablo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py",
>   line 47, in _execfile
>           exec(code, globals, locals)
>         File "C:\Users\pablo\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-uj2tljdw\cffi-1.12.3\setup.py",
>   line 127, in 
>           using R's own C-API through either:
>         File "C:\Users\pablo\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-uj2tljdw\cffi-1.12.3\setup.py",
>   line 105, in uses_msvc
>           else:
>         File "c:\users\pablo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\distutils\command\config.py",
>   line 227, in try_compile
>           self._compile(body, headers, include_dirs, lang)
>         File "c:\users\pablo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\distutils\command\config.py",
>   line 133, in _compile
>           self.compiler.compile([src], include_dirs=include_dirs)
>         File "c:\users\pablo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\distutils_msvccompiler.py",
>   line 304, in compile
>           self.initialize()
>         File "c:\users\pablo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\distutils_msvccompiler.py",
>   line 197, in initialize
>           vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
>         File "c:\users\pablo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py",
>   line 172, in msvc14_get_vc_env
>           return EnvironmentInfo(plat_spec, vc_min_ver=14.0).return_env()
>         File "c:\users\pablo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py",
>   line 771, in **init**
>           self.si = SystemInfo(self.ri, vc_ver)
>         File "c:\users\pablo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py",
>   line 480, in **init**
>           raise distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError(err)
>       distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools":
>   http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "C:\Users\pablo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-p0dcir5m\rpy2\setup.py",
>   line 184, in
>
> 'rpy2': ['doc/source/rpy2_logo.png', ]}   File
>   "c:\users\pablo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\distutils\core.py",
>
> line 108, in setup
>           _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
>         File "c:\users\pablo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py",
>   line 315, in **init**
>           self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs['setup_requires'])
>         File "c:\users\pablo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py",
>   line 361, in fetch_build_eggs
>           replace_conflicting=True,
>         File "c:\users\pablo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources__init__.py",
>   line 850, in resolve
>           dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
>         File "c:\users\pablo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources__init__.py",
>   line 1122, in best_match
>           return self.obtain(req, installer)
>         File "c:\users\pablo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources__init__.py",
>   line 1134, in obtain
>           return installer(requirement)
>         File "c:\users\pablo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py",
>   line 429, in fetch_build_egg
>           return cmd.easy_install(req)
>         File "c:\users\pablo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py",
>   line 665, in easy_install
>           return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
>         File "c:\users\pablo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py",
>   line 695, in install_item
>           dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
>         File "c:\users\pablo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py",
>   line 876, in install_eggs
>           return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
>         File "c:\users\pablo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py",
>   line 1115, in build_and_install
>           self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
>         File "c:\users\pablo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py",
>   line 1101, in run_setup
>           run_setup(setup_script, args)
>         File "c:\users\pablo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py",
>   line 251, in run_setup
>           raise
>         File "c:\users\pablo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\contextlib.py",
>   line 100, in **exit**
>           self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
>         File "c:\users\pablo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py",
>   line 198, in setup_context
>           yield
>         File "c:\users\pablo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\contextlib.py",
>   line 100, in **exit**
>           self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
>         File "c:\users\pablo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py",
>   line 169, in save_modules
>           saved_exc.resume()
>         File "c:\users\pablo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py",
>   line 144, in resume
>           six.reraise(type, exc, self._tb)
>         File "c:\users\pablo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources_vendor\six.py",
>   line 685, in reraise
>           raise value.with_traceback(tb)
>         File "c:\users\pablo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py",
>   line 157, in save_modules
>           yield saved
>         File "c:\users\pablo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py",
>   line 198, in setup_context
>           yield
>         File "c:\users\pablo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py",
>   line 248, in run_setup
>           DirectorySandbox(setup_dir).run(runner)
>         File "c:\users\pablo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py",
>   line 278, in run
>           return func()
>         File "c:\users\pablo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py",
>   line 246, in runner
>           _execfile(setup_script, ns)
>         File "c:\users\pablo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py",
>   line 47, in _execfile
>           exec(code, globals, locals)
>         File "C:\Users\pablo\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-uj2tljdw\cffi-1.12.3\setup.py",
>   line 127, in 
>           using R's own C-API through either:
>         File "C:\Users\pablo\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-uj2tljdw\cffi-1.12.3\setup.py",
>   line 105, in uses_msvc
>           else:
>         File "c:\users\pablo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\distutils\command\config.py",
>   line 227, in try_compile
>           self._compile(body, headers, include_dirs, lang)
>         File "c:\users\pablo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\distutils\command\config.py",
>   line 133, in _compile
>           self.compiler.compile([src], include_dirs=include_dirs)
>         File "c:\users\pablo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\distutils_msvccompiler.py",
>   line 304, in compile
>           self.initialize()
>         File "c:\users\pablo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\distutils_msvccompiler.py",
>   line 197, in initialize
>           vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
>         File "c:\users\pablo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py",
>   line 172, in msvc14_get_vc_env
>           return EnvironmentInfo(plat_spec, vc_min_ver=14.0).return_env()
>         File "c:\users\pablo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py",
>   line 771, in **init**
>           self.si = SystemInfo(self.ri, vc_ver)
>         File "c:\users\pablo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py",
>   line 480, in **init**
>           raise distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError(err)
>       distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools":
>   http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools
>       ---------------------------------------- ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
>   C:\Users\pablo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-p0dcir5m\rpy2\

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it you are missing Microsoft Visual Build Tools. Try installing it:
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

Then, restart your computer and update setup tools.

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

Once that it done, try installing rpy2 again.

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

you can download the binary file of rpy2 from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/
by searching it in the web page and use pip install 'that binary file' 
download binary file according to your python version